# Unable to enable oci8 PHP module

Tags: apache2, php

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

PHP 5.6

Apache 2.4

I followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/tassoevan/10392954), and used oci8-2.0.12 instead, the shared object exists but after I run `php5enmod oci8` then `service apache2 reload` phpinfo() doesn't list oci8.

I checked the apache logs and tested the config and no errors are present. I just gave www-data owner permissions on the instant client folder and still nothing.

Is there a log for php5enmod I need to know about or did I skip a step?

EDIT: I decided to try to disabled a module using phpdismod and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, because I didn't not change major versions and still had PHP5 I assumed that `php5enmod oci8` would enable the module, it does BUT IN THE WRONG FOLDER.

php5enmod adds a shortcut to the ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d but the 5.6 install is read from /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d. Using phpenmod instead of php5enmod solves the problem. One character difference, hours wasted.